# Simple way to detect if a string is a file or directory

Tags: ruby, file, path, directory

I'm trying to write a small ruby script that detects if a given argument is a file or a directory, based on the string containing a trailing `/` or not.

To be clear I'm **not** interested to know if the file or directory *actually exists*, in other words AFAIK `File.directory?` will not work for me.

Also all the methods I found in the standard library, such as `Pathname.basename` automatically remove the trailing `/` (if any). So doing something like this:

```
arg = "/foo/bar/baz/"
if File.basename(arg).include?("/")
    puts "#{arg} is a directory"
end
```

would not work.

Is there a concise way of doing this? Am I missing something?

I would rather not resort to regex if at all possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Does it depend on the last character only? If yes, `arg[-1]` is enough

```
if arg[-1] == ?/
    puts "#{arg} is a directory"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Since `/foo/bar/baz` can refer to *either* a file named `baz` in the `/foo/bar` directory or a directory named `/foo/bar/baz` there is no way to deterministically establish if it is a directory or a file without actually hitting the file system.

The rules for file names do not make a distinction between files and directories - in fact in many flavors of *nix a directory *is* a file just with special attributes. If you want to establish a rule for your application that states that directories will always end in a trailing separator then you can use:

```
is_directory = arg =~ %r{#{File.PATH_SEPARATOR}\Z}
```

or

```
is_directory = arg[=1] == File.PATH_SEPARATOR
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like this?

```
puts "#{arg} is a directory" if arg =~ %r|/\z|
```